# How can I use PostGIS to identify what state (California, Florida, ext.) a given latitude longitude is in?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gdal

I know PostGIS can identify if a given coordinate falls within a Polygon, is there a database that maps out all states into polygons?

Given a random USA based Lat/Long, I would like to be able to identify which state if falls within.

Answer (score 0):

`PostGIS` itself is "just" a spatial database extension for Postgres. It doesn't know US federal states by itself.

However, there are some datasets from data.gov that could help you:

- [State Boundary (Polygon)](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/state-boundary-polygon47f7e)
- [TIGER/Line Shapefile, 2017, nation, U.S., Current State and Equivalent National](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2017-nation-u-s-current-state-and-equivalent-national)

[PostGIS](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/loading_data.html) also provides some walkthroughs how to import shapefiles into Postgres.